# Oracle: Need for exists in correlated update

Tags: oracle, exists

I am doing SQL practice from the link below
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/updates-based-on-queries

In the subquery method, code is as below

```
UPDATE dest_tab tt
SET    (tt.code, tt.description) = (SELECT st.code, st.description
                                    FROM   source_tab st
                                    WHERE  st.id = tt.id)
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   source_tab
               WHERE  id = tt.id);
```

I can understand the correlation part using the join, but what is the use of EXISTS operator. As per article, it should exclude the records that aren't matched while updating destination table. But then that should be taken care by join condition, right? That is only records that have matching id between source and target. Is this because a WHERE clause is mandatory to avoid updating the full table, even though we have a equi-join between Source and target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `exists`, you'll update every row in `dest_tab`. So if there are any rows in `dest_tab` with no matching row in `source_tab`, they will have their columns set to null:

```
create table t1 (
  c1 int, c2 int
);

create table t2 (
  c1 int, c2 int
);


insert into t1 values ( 1, 1 );
insert into t1 values ( 2, 2 );

insert into t2 values ( 1, 999 );

commit;

update t1
set    c2 = ( 
  select c2 from t2
  where  t1.c1 = t2.c1
);

select * from t1;

C1     C2       
    1       999 
    2    <null>
```

Adding the `exists` clause avoids this issue:

```
rollback;

update t1
set    c2 = ( 
  select c2 from t2
  where  t1.c1 = t2.c1
)
where  exists (
  select null from t2
  where  t1.c1 = t2.c1
);

select * from t1;

C1    C2    
    1    999 
    2      2
```